# Как понять, что произошло подтверждение личности аккаунта разработчика Google Play?

Tags: google-play, мобильная-разработка

В четверг 30.07.20 создал аккаунт разработчика в Google Play, отправил фото паспорта. Сегодня пришло письмо следующего содержания:
"Добро пожаловать в Google Play!    Спасибо, что присоединились. Вы стали частью сообщества разработчиков, чьи приложения и игры приносят пользу и радость миллиардам пользователей." и так далее.
Однако функция подтверждения личности из Google Play Console не исчезла:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, является ли мой аккаунт подтверждённым или мне нужно сделать ещё что-то?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, подтверждения не произошло, по причине того, что я закрыл подпись на паспорте:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дабы второй раз не мучатся с паспортом, скинул водительское удостоверение и, через несколько часов успешно прошёл идентификацию